# Powershell error when running jest script

Tags: node.js, powershell, jestjs

I am trying to analyze memory leaks when running jest script, so I am launching this script in my console:

`node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest.ps1 --runInBand --logHeapUsage`

But I always receive this error message:

```
$basedir=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, the command to run on Windows is:

`node --expose-gc ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand --logHeapUsage`